# How to deal with treatment effects that occurs multiple times at different time for each individual ID

Tags: r, stata, matching, treatment-effect

I've been searching for a long time for this issue and couldn't find the proper answer so I post a question here.

Here I put the data set example first.

```
**ID  Time      Treated**
1      1           0
1      2           1
1      3           1
1      4           0
1      5           0

2      1           1
2      2           1
2      3           1
2      4           0

3      1           0
3      2           1
3      3           1
3      4           0 
3      5           1
3      6           1
```

Based on the data set example, the treatment occurs multiple times at different times for each individual ID. 
My goal is to divide each individual into treatment groups and control groups and then conduct score matching based on the demographic variables.

What I've found were all about the situation that the treatment occurs at different times through each individual but the treatment lasts through the whole time. (I've searched dynamic treatment effects, time varying treatment effects, inverse probability weighted score etc)
So in this case, the data set example looks like this:

```
**ID    Time    Treated**
1      1           0
1      2           0
1      3           0

2      1           0
2      2           1
2      3           1
2      4           1

3      1           0
3      2           1
3      3           1
```

It would be appreciated if you give me any idea about my situation.
Any intuitive explanation would be more welcome!

Comment: How is treatment assigned? Is the effect instantaneous and does it last?

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov Hi. The above example of the two data set is mine. So the treatment effects occur instantaneously and can be last until the end of the i's time or they may occur multiple times (For example, if t=1, 2, 3, ..., 10, it can occur at t=2 through t=4 and stops and then can occur again at t=6 through t=9)

Comment: What about the first question?

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov ? My question is what kind of treatment effect should I use in that situation.

Comment: I understand about the timing. Let me try to be clearer. Who decides which observations are treated and when? Once an observation gets a treatment,  you say the effect is instantaneous, but it the effect wear off? In other words, is it more like an aspirin or more like a vaccine?